# hide item when show another

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i close an item(.sub-menu) when another is open please ?

This is my code

```js
 $('.menu-item-has-children > a').attr('aria-expanded', false);
  var click_item = function () {
      $('.menu-item-has-children > a').on('click', function(){
          var EltToToggle = $(this).next('.sub-menu');

          if ($(this).attr('href') === "#") {
              event.preventDefault();
          }

          if ($(this).attr('aria-expanded') === "true") {
              $(this).attr('aria-expanded', false);
              $(this).removeClass('is-opened');
              EltToToggle.removeClass('show');
          } else {
              $(this).attr('aria-expanded', true);
              $(this).addClass('is-opened');
              EltToToggle.addClass('show');
          }
      });
  }
  click_item();

  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var sub_menu = $(".sub-menu");
    var except_body = $(".menu");

    // If the target of the click isn't the sub_menu
    if (!except_body.is(e.target) && except_body.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      sub_menu.removeClass('show');
      $(".menu-item-has-children > a").attr('aria-expanded', false);
      $(".menu-item-has-children > a").removeClass('is-opened');
      // click_item();
      console.log("ok")
      }
  });
```

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  margin: 10px;
}
.menu-item-has-children {
    position: relative;
}
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  left: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 2rem);
  transform: translate(-50%, 2rem);
  padding: 1rem 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: .6rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.show {
  display: block!important;
}
.menu-item-has-children>a {
position: relative
}

.menu-item-has-children>a:after {
    top: 2rem;
    right: 1.5rem;
}

.menu-item-has-children>a:after {
    content: "\f077";
    font-family: FontAwesome!important;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-alt: "";
    speak: none;
    right: 1.6rem;
    top: 2.3rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    transition: -webkit-transform .25s ease;
    transition: transform .25s ease;
    transition: transform .25s ease,-webkit-transform .25s ease;
}
.menu-item-has-children>a:after {
    top: 2rem;
    right: 1.5rem;
}
 .menu-item-has-children>a[aria-expanded=true]:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.sub-menu a {
  color: white; 
 }
.sub-menu.one {
  background: teal;
  width: 300px;
}
.sub-menu.two {
  background: purple; 
  width: 300px;
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">

  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#" aria-expanded="false" class="">
                               Item 1
           </a>

    <ul class="sub-menu one">
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#" aria-current="page">
                                [Current] Lvl2. Children 1
            </a>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">
                                Lvl2. Children 2 with long text lorem ipsum
            </a>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                                Link 2
            </a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">
                                Lvl3. Children 1
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#" aria-current="page">
                                [Current] Lvl3. Children 2 with long text lorem ipsum
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#" target="_blank" class="external-link">
                                [_blank] Lvl3. Children 3
            <span class="icon-link-external" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="external-link">
                                [_blank] Lvl2. Children 4
            <span class="icon-link-external" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#" aria-expanded="false" class="">
                                Link 2
         </a>

    <ul class="sub-menu two">
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#" aria-current="page">
                                [Current] Lvl2. Children 1
            </a>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">
                                Lvl2. Children 2 with long text lorem ipsum
            </a>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                                Lvl2. Children 3 with children
            </a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">
                                Lvl3. Children 1
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#" aria-current="page">
                                [Current] Lvl3. Children 2 with long text lorem ipsum
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#" target="_blank" class="external-link">
                                [_blank] Lvl3. Children 3
            <span class="icon-link-external" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="external-link">
                                [_blank] Lvl2. Children 4
            <span class="icon-link-external" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>



</ul>
```

when i click on the link ('.menu-item-has-children > a') i want to show the concerning item (.sub-menu) and when i click on another(.sub-menu) i want to show it and hide the other one (WITHOUT CHANGING HTML CODE, JUST JS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the whole thing inside your else block.

```js
$('.menu-item-has-children > a').attr('aria-expanded', false);
  var click_item = function () {
      $('.menu-item-has-children > a').on('click', function(){
          var EltToToggle = $(this).next('.sub-menu');

          if ($(this).attr('href') === "#") {
              event.preventDefault();
          }

          if ($(this).attr('aria-expanded') === "true") {
              $(this).attr('aria-expanded', false);
              $(this).removeClass('is-opened');
              EltToToggle.removeClass('show');
          } else {
              //Reset all
              $('.menu-item-has-children > a').attr('aria-expanded', false)
              $('.menu-item-has-children > a').removeClass('is-opened')
              $('.menu-item-has-children > a').next('.sub-menu').removeClass('show');
              
              $(this).attr('aria-expanded', true);
              $(this).addClass('is-opened');
              EltToToggle.addClass('show');
          }


      });
  }
  click_item();

  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var sub_menu = $(".sub-menu");
    var except_body = $(".menu");

    // If the target of the click isn't the sub_menu
    if (!except_body.is(e.target) && except_body.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      sub_menu.removeClass('show');
      $(".menu-item-has-children > a").attr('aria-expanded', false);
      $(".menu-item-has-children > a").removeClass('is-opened');
      // click_item();
      console.log("ok")
      }
  });
```

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  margin: 10px;
}
.menu-item-has-children {
    position: relative;
}
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  left: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 2rem);
  transform: translate(-50%, 2rem);
  padding: 1rem 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: .6rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.show {
  display: block!important;
}
.menu-item-has-children>a {
position: relative
}

.menu-item-has-children>a:after {
    top: 2rem;
    right: 1.5rem;
}

.menu-item-has-children>a:after {
    content: "\f077";
    font-family: FontAwesome!important;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-alt: "";
    speak: none;
    right: 1.6rem;
    top: 2.3rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    transition: -webkit-transform .25s ease;
    transition: transform .25s ease;
    transition: transform .25s ease,-webkit-transform .25s ease;
}
.menu-item-has-children>a:after {
    top: 2rem;
    right: 1.5rem;
}
 .menu-item-has-children>a[aria-expanded=true]:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.sub-menu a {
  color: white; 
 }
.sub-menu.one {
  background: teal;
  width: 300px;
}
.sub-menu.two {
  background: purple; 
  width: 300px;
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">

  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#" aria-expanded="false" class="">
                               Item 1
           </a>

    <ul class="sub-menu one">
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#" aria-current="page">
                                [Current] Lvl2. Children 1
            </a>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">
                                Lvl2. Children 2 with long text lorem ipsum
            </a>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                                Link 2
            </a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">
                                Lvl3. Children 1
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#" aria-current="page">
                                [Current] Lvl3. Children 2 with long text lorem ipsum
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#" target="_blank" class="external-link">
                                [_blank] Lvl3. Children 3
            <span class="icon-link-external" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="external-link">
                                [_blank] Lvl2. Children 4
            <span class="icon-link-external" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#" aria-expanded="false" class="">
                                Link 2
         </a>

    <ul class="sub-menu two">
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#" aria-current="page">
                                [Current] Lvl2. Children 1
            </a>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">
                                Lvl2. Children 2 with long text lorem ipsum
            </a>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                                Lvl2. Children 3 with children
            </a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">
                                Lvl3. Children 1
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#" aria-current="page">
                                [Current] Lvl3. Children 2 with long text lorem ipsum
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#" target="_blank" class="external-link">
                                [_blank] Lvl3. Children 3
            <span class="icon-link-external" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="external-link">
                                [_blank] Lvl2. Children 4
            <span class="icon-link-external" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>



</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to hide all items and then show only tree branch that you need.

To show branch just go through all items from clicked one to root one.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'm still a beginner on js could you help me on how to do it in the example (snippet) Please ?

Answer (score 0):

`$('.menu-item-has-children > a').attr('aria-expanded', false);`
call this and also i see you are using this class `is-opened` so whenever the click item on list is called call the above function and remove the class from the DOM so that other list's opened are closed and then calle this on the current one so that it's opened.

or using jquery you can call change the style property to display none.

Comment: thanks for answer, here, i have an 'if' condition, where can i put `$('.menu-item-has-children > a').attr('aria-expanded', false);` ? and i didn't understand what you said about the '.is-opened' class

Comment: calling this code 
`$( ".menu" ).find('.is-opened' );` if this gives results true then removing the class from the element in first if condition and then adding to the element that is clicked now.